# Preventing function from rendering in an infinite loop React

Tags: reactjs

Why is my SearchJobs function rendering in an infinite loop and how do I prevent that??

```
export default function JobsList() {

  const searchTerm = useParams().searchTerm;
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const { estPreview, setEstPreview } = useContext(EstPreviewContext)


  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchJobs() {
      const fetchedJobs = await searchJobs(searchTerm);
      setJobs(fetchedJobs)
    }
    fetchJobs();
  }, [searchTerm]);


  async function searchJobs(searchTerm) {
    try {
      console.log("search")
      const postingJobsSubcollection = await getDocs(collectionGroup(database, "postingJobs"));
      if (searchTerm === '*') {
        const fetchedPostingJobsData = postingJobsSubcollection.docs.map(
          (doc) => doc.data())
          .filter((job) => job.isJobActive);
        return fetchedPostingJobsData;
      }
      else {
        const filteredJobs = postingJobsSubcollection.docs.filter(doc => {
          const jobData = doc.data();
          const normalizedJobTitle = jobData.jobTitle.toLowerCase();
          const normalizedJobDescription = jobData.jobDescription.toLowerCase();
          const normalizedSearchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();

          const jobTitleMatch = normalizedJobTitle.includes(normalizedSearchTerm);
          const jobDescriptionMatch = normalizedJobDescription.includes(normalizedSearchTerm);

          return (
            (jobTitleMatch || jobDescriptionMatch) &&
            jobData.isJobActive
          )

        });

        const fetchedPostingJobsData = filteredJobs.map(doc => doc.data());
        return fetchedPostingJobsData;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error retrieving jobs", error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBox />
       <Container style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <JobCard postingJobsData={jobs} />
        <JobDetails />
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Why are both my functions rendering in an infinite loop?
searchJobs()
The console.log is rendering non-stop and not getting to the catch block.
I'm sure I'm missing something essential in React, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useCallback hook to memoize the searchJobs function and prevent it from being recreated on each render. By wrapping searchJobs with useCallback and providing an empty dependency array, you ensure that the function is only created once and won't trigger unnecessary re-renders.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function JobsList() {
  const searchTerm = useParams().searchTerm;
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const { estPreview, setEstPreview } = useContext(EstPreviewContext);

  const searchJobs = useCallback(async (searchTerm) => {
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchJobs() {
      const fetchedJobs = await searchJobs(searchTerm);
      setJobs(fetchedJobs);
    }
    fetchJobs();
  }, [searchTerm, searchJobs]);

  // rest of your component code...
}
```